# How to extract multiple excel rows from multiple workbooks based on python list using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

first thank you for your time and consideration.

My code successfully scans a folder a .xlsx workbooks and extracts data from each wkbook wherever it finds a match for on a singular input value (search term) using openpyxl. It takes this data, stores it in lists and writes it to a new .xlsx workbook using pandas dataframes.

My question: how do I go from searching a singular input search term to a list of multiple input values using the existing packages? I tried to do this with a "searchlist" in my code but it does not work- the .xlsx output has no data.

```
for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for row in ws['A1':'EE30000']:
    for cell in row:
        for cell.value in searchlist:
            if cell.value == searchlist:
                WorkbookNameList.append(f)
                OIDList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value)
                BUList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
                AcctList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).value)
                ToolRevList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=10).value)
                ToolCOSList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=28).value)
                TAMBAList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=141).value)
                CommentsList.append(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=34).value)
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\extract')
df = DataFrame({'Workbook Name' : WorkbookNameList, 'OID': OIDList,'BU': BUList,'Managed Account': AcctList, 'Revenue Tool Amount': ToolRevList, 'Tool COS': ToolCOSList, 'Customer Technology Node' : TAMBAList, 'BU OID Comment' : CommentsList})
df.to_excel('Output2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question. If you're simply looking to search a worksheet for different terms then use a dictionary for this – search StackOverflow for examples of how to do this.

Comment: thanks Charlie. I did some further research and looks like pandas merge is what I am looking for